# How can I use a regular expression to grab a single word?

Tags: regex, replace

For my work training they are training me in regular expressions, but the guy that is training me is very busy, and I don't want to bother him for help. I need to get just single words from the following sentence: "Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels."
I am using the following format:

```
"Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.".replace(//gi,"")
```

For getting crazy I used the following:

```
"Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.".replace(/(\s\w+)+\.$/gi,"")
```

But how do I query the rest of the words?

Comment: how about match `[^\s]+\b` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use regex, you could do this:

The regex:

```
[^\s]+\b
```

Working regex example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yyxrh/

Javascript:

```
var str = 'Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.';
var RE = /[^\s]+\b/gi;
var match = str.match(RE);

console.log(match);
```

Output:

```
["Crazy", "Fredrick", "bought", "many", "very", "exquisite", "opal", "jewels"]
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yyxrh/

Answer (score 2):

Replace is not needed. You can just call split:

```
var words = "Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels".split(/ +/g);
//=> OUTPUT: ["Crazy", "Fredrick", "bought", "many", "very", "exquisite", "opal", "jewels"]
```